# how to get date format like yyyy-mm-dd am in java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I need to get date format like:

```
"yyyy-mm-dd am"
```

or

```
"yyyy-mm-dd pm"
```

In Java for Android

I do not need current time, only **yyyy-mm-dd** plus **am**/**pm**

how to make it directly ?

i use the method below to get current date:

```
    private static String getDate(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        return sdf.format(c.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");` will produce hours:mins with am/pm

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
"h:mm a" Result 12:08 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use these below lines of code...There is only one problem with the **SimpleDateFormat** is that when ever you change the device language to another language than **SimpleDateFormat**'s string also changes with the language which can create **problem** in yours application..Therefore i suggest you if you do **not** want to  change the **date** string according the application language changes than Use below concept which become helpful for you Or Just simply use **SimpleDateFormat** for not changing the application language to another langauge.

```
     Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
     String AM_PM;

      if(ci.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)
        {
             AM_PM ="AM";
        }
        else
        {
             AM_PM ="PM";
        }
        String CiDateTime = "" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
            (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
            ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+AM_PM;

         System.out.println("time=========================================="+CiDateTime);
```

**Output:-**

```
 time==========================================2015-5-20 PM
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd a");
```

Output will be

`2015-34-20 AM`

EDIT

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd a");
```

this will produce an output of

`2015-05-20 AM`

Comment: simple and good answer. +1.

Comment: Check your `m`'s. Should be capital `M`'s for _month in year_ (assuming that's what OP actually wants).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the reference for SimpleDateFormat in Android for a list of all the symbols and what they represent.
[SimpleDateFormat Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)